# C how to copy by value?

Tags: c

I'm working on the following function to parse CIDR notation and eventually return an array of all IP addresses.

I am having a problem at this line though: `network_addr = last_addr = addr.s_addr;`

I need 3 variables that hold the network address, last address, and the original address so I can apply bit shift operators to them. But, at the moment it seems to be acting on a reference of `addr.s_addr`.

How do I make a copy by value?

```
int parse_ipv4_cidr(char *ip_cidr)
{
    struct in_addr addr;
    int cidr;
    char *token;
    uint32_t netmask, network_addr, last_addr;

    token = strtok(ip_cidr, "/");

    /*
     *  Validate IPV4 CIDR address
     */
    if(!inet_aton(token, &addr) ||
       !(token = strtok(NULL, "/")) ||
       (atoi(token) < 0 || atoi(token) > 32))
    {
        printf("Invalid CIDR notation. Example format: 192.0.0.1/21\n");
        return 1;
    }

    cidr = atoi(token);
    network_addr = last_addr = addr.s_addr;

    /*
     *  Create the netmask
     */
    netmask = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    netmask <<= 32 - cidr;
    netmask = ntohl(netmask);

    /*
     *  Calculate network address
     */
    network_addr = network_addr & netmask;

    /*
     *  Calculate last address
     */
    last_addr = (last_addr & netmask) + ~netmask;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it's *acting on a reference of `addr.s_addr`*?

Comment: Because when I `printf("%x\n%x\n", network_addr, last_addr)` both memory locations are the same.

Comment: @Torra `network_addr` and `last_addr` are unsigned integers, that will print their values, not their location in memory.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves ahhh! I'm confusing something here. Thank you.

Comment: @Torra You can print the memory addresses with `printf("%p\n%p\n", (void *) &network_addr, (void *) &last_addr);`. But I don't see how that might help you.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves initially I was confused, and thought "lets print the memory addresses to see if they're the same". But I see now what I was doing wrong.

Comment: Hmmm: `netmask <<= 32 - cidr;` -->> `netmask <<= (32 - cidr);`

Comment: **C does not have references!** It is all by-value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue is not with references / copy by value (you are already copying by value). It seems to me like you messed up on network / host byte order.

The `sa_addr` field of `struct in_addr` is in network byte order; when you copy that to `network_addr` and `last_addr`, you should convert it to host byte order, since you'll be doing shifting and other manipulations.

Furthermore, for some reason the code assumes that `netmask` is in network byte order, whereas in fact it is in host byte order. Things do not add up.

Just stick to host byte order and everything should work.

Change this line:

```
network_addr = last_addr = addr.s_addr;
```

To:

```
network_addr = last_addr = ntohl(addr.s_addr);
```

And delete this line:

```
netmask = ntohl(netmask);
```

You probably want to add `return network_addr;` in the end and possibly change the return type to `uint32_t`.

Comment: This makes sense actually, I forgot network byte order is big endian, my host is little endian.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to `malloc` your new variables, then `memcpy` the old variable to your new variables.